# Koethe Conjecture and a Nil Problem of Jacobson Radical

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a ring with identity, and $e^2=e\in R$ such that both $eJe$ and $(1-e)J(1-e)$ are nil, where $J=J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$. When $R$ is commutative, it is easy to see that $J$ is nil. Indeed, the sum  $ej+(1-e)j=j$ is nilpotent, for every $j\in J$ in the commutative setting. I guess that if Koethe's Conjecture holds for $R$, then $J$ is nil too. (The conjecture is true for the commutative rings.)

Any suggestion/help is appreciated in advance!

Comment: Am I guessing right that your question is your "guess"?

Comment: @rschwieb:  I do not understand the tenor of your comment. What a "doubt" does there exist about the "guess"? Is it presented before by another person?

Comment: You have written a paragraph of statements without any questions, and I just wanted to make sure I was thinking about your intended problem, that is all.  Sometimes questions come out not as they were intended to, and I'm just playing it safe by asking.

Comment: @rschwieb: Yes, I meant if Koethe Conjecture holds, could we deduce the assertion I raised, i.e., is the nilness of $eJe$ and $(1-e)J(1-e)$ yield that of $J$?